# Búsqueda filtrada en MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

Buenas noches, tengo el siguiente código.

```
<?php
    require_once 'config.php';

    $search_string = $_GET['search_string'];
    $query = array('title' => new MongoRegex("/^$search_string/i"));    
    $cursor = $collection->find($query);

    $result = array();  
    foreach($cursor as $k => $row){
        array_push($result, $row);
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Dónde pasa a $query por un array de title, pero también quiero pasar author que sería otro campo para que me traiga información ya sea si coincide title o author. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para eso usas el operador `$or`. Y ojo, el `$or` espera **un array de arrays**:

```
$query_title  = ['title'  => new MongoRegex("/^$search_string/i")];    
$query_author = ['author' => new MongoRegex("/^$search_string/i")];    

$cursor = $collection->find([
  '$or' => [
    $query_title,
    $query_author
  ]
]);
```